# document.write iframe causing white screen

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, document.write, double-click-advertising

I'm having an issue when utilizing doubleclick floodlight analytics. When a user clicks on a button, the floodlight should fire and open a new window (as it does). The problem occurs when the user goes back to the original screen and the page is white. You have to reload the page to get back to it.

HTML - clicking button opens new window and fires handleThirdFloodClick

```html
<button role="link" target="_blank" href="URLHERE/locations" onclick="handleThirdFloodClick();">
  <span>Find A LOCATION</span>
</button>
```

JavaScript - doubleclick code fires when button is clicked

```js
function handleThirdFloodClick(){
  var axel = Math.random() + "";
  var a = axel * 10000000000000;
  document.write('<iframe src="https://XXXXXXX.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=XXXXXXX;type=XXXXXX;cat=XXXXXXXX;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;tfua=;npa=;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
}
```

The two "Find a location" buttons and the $5 off button are all causing this white screen.

I am unable to reproduce the white screen using liveserver, but it shows up on a production site. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I solved this with a bandaid - instead of having the button open a new target="_bank", I just have the URL redirect thus not having a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else runs into this, it's a poor example from Google.

The problem is that **ord=' + a + '** is in this is beyond me, it's an undefined variable that will break many sites because it can't be evaluated. You need to make it **ord='1'** and that should fix it.

But, this also points out that error trapping is not working on the site as well, so if you can fix both, that would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 'Support document.write' box checked in your GTM tag?